# Getting {“statusCode”:500,”error”:”Internal Server Error”,”message”:”An internal server error occurred.”} when accessing kibana dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, apm

```
{"statusCode":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"An internal server error occurred."}
```

I'm getting above error on the browser when trying to access an already deployed kibana service's Kibana dashboard.

By restarting the Elasticsearch, Kibana and APM server containers, I was able to solve this issue. But after a few days, the service crashed again throwing the same error, and we had to restart all 3 services as before. Any idea why this is happening? And is it an issue with the load of data that was logged into the Elasticsearch?

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Internal Server Error does not tell what is the actual error. If you have access to error logs, you might find the actual cause of error there.